# Compare Objects in Array and Remove Duplicate & Update - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that presents as follows:

```
0: Object
ConsolidatedItem_catalogId: "080808"
ConsolidatedItem_catalogItem: "undefined"
ConsolidatedItem_cost: "0"
ConsolidatedItem_description: "Test Catalog Item"
ConsolidatedItem_imageFile: "27617647008728.jpg"
ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber: "1234"
ConsolidatedItem_quantity: "1"
ConsolidatedItem_source: "CAT"
ConsolidatedItem_status: "02"
ConsolidatedItem_umCode: "EA"

1: Object
ConsolidatedItem_catalogId: ""
ConsolidatedItem_catalogItem: "undefined"
ConsolidatedItem_cost: "0"
ConsolidatedItem_description: "ALARM,SHUTDOWN SYSTEM,AXIOM,XP3, 0-1500 PSIG, HIGH AND LOW PRES Testing"
ConsolidatedItem_imageFile: ""
ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber: "10008"
ConsolidatedItem_quantity: "1"
ConsolidatedItem_source: "INV"
ConsolidatedItem_status: "02"
ConsolidatedItem_umCode: "EA"
```

I'm trying to update and remove an object if it's added again, or update the object. Preferably update the object with the new value. My code is as follows:

```
var result = $.grep(finalObject, function(e) {
            return e.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber == o.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber;
        });
        console.log(result);
        if (result.length == 0) {
            finalObject.push(o);
            shoppingCounter = finalObject.length;
            $('#numberShoppedItems').text(shoppingCounter);
            console.log(finalObject);
        } else if (result.length == 1) {    
            finalObject.filter(function(x){
                result = x;
                console.log(result);
                return x == result.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber;

            }); 
        } else {
            alert('Multiples Found');
        } 
    }
```

I've tried multiple ways of getting the exact object and manipulating the data, however they've all failed. I would prefer to update the object, say if `CatalogItem_itemNumber` held the same value, if the `CatalogItem_quantity` was different - add the `CatalogItem_quantity` values together and update the array of objects.

I don't need an exact answer, a nudge in the right direction would do wonders though. I've looked at several of the related questions over the past couple of hours but none of them seem to address the issue. If you know of a question that has an answer, feel free to just link that as well. I may have missed it.

No Underscore.js please

Comment: Why no jQuery if you are already using it? Or: Why are you mixing `$.grep` with `Array::filter`?

Comment: I removed the jQuery limitation. It's confusing, we're refactoring without jQuery, but if it makes it easier for now that's fine.

Comment: No, no, avoiding jQuery for this task is a good idea, I only was surprised to see that you did you use it yourself. Just refactor the `$.grep` out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the following manner:

1.) Verify object is not empty.

2.) Use `.some()` on object to iterate through it.

3.) Check if the `finalObject`, which is now `e`, has a match for the key in my temporary object I assemble, `o`.

4.) Update the values that need updating and return true;

Note: Originally I was going to remove the object by its index and replace it with a new object. This too can work by using `.splice()` and getting the index of the current object in that array you're in.

Here is the updating version:

```
if (o.ConsolidatedItem_quantity != '') {

    var result = $.grep(finalObject, function(e) {
        return e.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber == o.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber;
    });
    if (result.length == 0) {...}
    else {
        finalObject.some(function (e) {
            if(e.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber == o.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber){
                var a;
                a = +e.ConsolidatedItem_quantity + +o.ConsolidatedItem_quantity;
                e.ConsolidatedItem_quantity = a.toString();
                document.getElementById(o.ConsolidatedItem_itemNumber).value=a;
                return true;
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find the matching record, you may update it by using `$.extend`

```
        $.extend(result[0], o)
```

This will update the object in finalObject array in-place.

Alternatively, if you want to use the filter, you will need to insert the new object in the array.

```
        finalObject = finalObject.filter(function(x) {
            return x !== result[0];

        }); 
        finalObject.push(o)
```

Here we are allowing all the records that are not not equal to result to be returned in the resultant array that is received in finalObject. In next line, we are adding the new record.